# how create calender view and mark date range specific colour in calender?

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, calendar

(I post this question after lot of searching ,please, expect some expert help )

I am doing my project using Laravel 5. I take set of date from my sql database. I want to add calender to my site and mark my dates range some specific colour .

Example : I take from database 2015/11/10 - 2015/11/15 and I want to colour this part red in calender .

I wand to create calender like this image.I create view using Laravel blade template formate.

[image]

I do lot of web search to find how to make like this functionality but I couldn't find any reference. I am new for web developing and I face lot of trouble to implement this functionality as last two days.

I hope some expert help or some references to do this. Please, If this question not suitable for this community  , give me suitable community links.

regard.

Comment: Have you looked at this calendar: https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar ? Once you have it working, you can colour the event day/s by playing a bit with it. Don't expect to always find the perfect answer when you search. Most of the times you will need to find a similar answer and play with it until you get what you want

Comment: @sailens Thanks lot of . I will try it.